# Postprocessing of image segmentation

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, data-fitting

I have a 3D NumPy dataset [images number, x, y] in which the probability that the pixel belongs to a class is stored as a float (0-1). I would like to correct the wrong segmented pixels (with high performance).

The probabilities are part of a movie in which objects are moving from right to left and possibly back again. The basic idea is that I fit the pixels with a Gaussian function or comparable function and look at around 15-30 images `( [i-15 : i+15 ,x, y] )`. It is very probable that if the previous 5 pixels and the following 5 pixels are classified in this class, this pixel also belongs to this class.

If I solve this problem with looping it takes too much time (although I use multiprocessing and multi-threading). The size of the NumPy array is [300, 600,600] or higher but the images are always square.

Here my example code with comments:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy import exp
import numpy as np


def gaus(x, a, x0, sigma):
    return a*exp(-(x-x0)**2/(2*sigma**2))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # output_AI = [imageNr, x, y] example 5, 2, 2
    # At position [2][1][1] is the error, the pixels before and after were classified to the class but not this pixel.
    # The objects do not move in such a speed, so the probability should be corrected.
    outputAI = np.array([[[0.1, 0], [0, 0]], [[0.8, 0.3], [0, 0.2]], [[1, 0.1], [0, 0.2]],
                         [[0.1, 0.3], [0, 0.2]], [[0.8, 0.3], [0, 0.2]]])
    correct_output = np.zeros(outputAI.shape)


    # I correct now in this example only all pixels in image 3, in the code a loop runs over the whole 3D array and
    # corrects every image and every pixel separately
    size_of_array = outputAI.shape
    x = range(size_of_array[0])
    for i in range(size_of_array[1]):
        for k in range(size_of_array[2]):
            args, cov = curve_fit(gaus, x, outputAI[:, i, k])
            correct_output[2, i, k] = gaus(2, *args)

    print(correct_output[2])
    # [[9.88432346e-01 2.10068763e-01]
    # [6.02428922e-20 2.07921125e-01]]
    # The wrong pixel at position [0][0] was corrected from 0.2 to almost 1, the others are still not assigned
    # to the class.
```

Comment: could you post some code? some sort of MWE?

Comment: I added a example code

Comment: Have you considered compiling your code with numba or cython?

Comment: Sry I've never done this before, tomorrow I'll take a look at your idea.  What's the upside? Currently the solution is to split it by multiprocessing and multithreading.

Comment: Multiprocessing still runs the python interpreter, and multithreading is pretty much useless for sequential code in python because of the GIL. numba will actually compile your code into something much faster than a python loop.

Comment: I just took a look at the library and I think this might solve my problem. I'm going to test it out in a little sample tomorrow. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sry that I contact you again. What must I do to use the curve_fit function of scipy.optimize? The numba compiler always ends with an error: 


Compilation is falling back to object mode WITH looplifting enabled because Function "numba" failed type inference due to: Untyped global name 'curve_fit': cannot determine Numba type of <class 'function'>